# insert data from filestream in local storage chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have created table in local storage and also succeeded in insert single row in local storage but when i use the streamed text file to insert it in local storage line by line then the data is not inserted. Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

In absense of actual code, the only ssuggestion I can give is to base64-encode your file text before you store it:

```
localStorage.setItem( btoa( myfiletext ) );
```

Don't forget to decode it with `atob` when you fetch it again.